# Demoting a Python Subprocess

Tags: python

Is it possible to have a main Python process run as root, but then start a Python subprocess (multiprocessing) run as a different user? I also want that user's home directory and shell settings to apply just like if the Python interpreter had been started by that user.

Right now, when using os.setuid and gid, the permissions are correct, but the home directory is still incorrect as you'd expect:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.setgid(1000)
>>> os.setuid(1000)
>>> print os.getuid()
1000
>>> print os.getgid()
1000
>>> f = open('/etc/shadow')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/shadow'
>>> os.system('echo $HOME')
/root
0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: And yes, I'm aware that os.system is deprecated in favor of subprocess. However, for testing purposes os.system is much easier.

Comment: why not just login as that user?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham because it's running as a damon that will descalate it's sub processes as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
os.environ['HOME'] = '/home/blah'
os.system("ls ~")
```

AFAIK, this is as good as you are likely to get, because installations with network home directories, or users with bash profiles that set HOME to wacky values aren't going to be replicable in pure Python, and could have side effects.

Comment: I know I can set the variables manually, but I was hoping for something built into Python for this purpose. More likely to avoid bugs that way.

Comment: Good point!  Though, in principle, the shell profile variables and PAM could set the user's home directory to some arbitrarily wacky value, so this problem doesn't look solvable in principle, even if parsing /etc/passwd would work in many cases.